# UINavigationBar not displaying title in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Trying to set a NavBar programaticaly, and my title isn't showing in the navbar. Any ideas as to whats happening?

```
UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
navbar.topItem.title = @"My accounts";

[self.view addSubview:navbar];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your use of the `UINavigationBar`.

Read the documentation for [`UINavigationController` programming here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You should not be creating your own `UINavigationBar` and adding it as a subview to your view controller's view.

The correct thing to do is to create a `UINavigationController` and add your view controller to its stack.

So something like this:

```
CustomViewController *myViewController = ...// whatever initialization you do
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
```

Each view controller has its own `UINavigationItem` that the navigation controller uses to set up the navigation bar's view when that view controller is at the top of the stack.

So in your `CustomViewController.m`, possibly in the `init` method or in `viewDidLoad`,

you can set up the navigation item by doing something like this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"whatever";
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...// create a UIBarButtonItem and set it here if you want a button on the right side of the navigation bar
```

So once again, you do not touch the navigation bar directly or add it to your view hierarchy. The `UINavigationController` handles all of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"the title";
```

as setting navBar.topItem.title will not work in all circumstances.

Comment: Doesn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: are you using UITabbarController?